# Selenium module Troublshooting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
username = ""
password = ""
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://facebook.com")
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(username)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(password)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

however i run into this error:

> C:\Users\mali03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe 
>   C:/Users/mali03/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/exe.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\mali03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.13.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
>       stdin=PIPE)
>     File "C:\Users\mali03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "C:\Users\mali03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/mali03/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/exe.py", line 5, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>     File "C:\Users\mali03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.13.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 160, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>     File "C:\Users\mali03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.13.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: This is a duplicate. Also make sure you download the geckodriver version that fits your firefox version.

Comment: @pasch013 Bless your soul. I am quite new to programming and a little push goes a long way :)

Comment: No worries, I struggled with this error a lot too. Message me if you have further problems.